# How to get height of a 100% width image with auto height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this case, I set an image with `width: 100%` and `height: auto` (actual image size is 362x614). I need to get height of image for another step.

Here is my code:

```
<img class="phone" src="img/phone2.png">
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   phoneSlider();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   phoneSlider()
});

function phoneSlider(){
   var phoneMaskWidth = $(".phone").width();
   var phoneMaskHeight = $(".phone").height();
       console.log(phoneMaskWidth + "|" + phoneMaskHeight);
       .......
}
```

Then, I check in the console, and the result: **`362|0`**. Why is phoneMaskHeight showing 0 and how can I get the real height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code from `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()`. The browser needs to load the image (or at least the image header) before it can calculate its width and height. Document ready event can fire *before* the browser has chance to have a look at the image.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Kd2Yv/2/); change the image source (or empty browser cache), run and look at the console

Comment: it's work for me, but that way is too risky for this time.. thanks for your answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = $(".phone").attr('src');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Increazon/A5QJM/1/)**

Comment: why img.src outside onload function?

Comment: The assignment to the "src" attribute will trigger the loading of the image. So you can't have that in the #onload callback, otherwise nothing will trigger the loading of the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img.phone").on('load', function() { alert( this.height ); });
```

This  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers load images asynchronously and until the image is fully loaded its height will be unknown.

As others have suggested you will need to attach your code to the "onload" event that is fired when the image is loaded, but that will force you to change your whole *phoneSlider* method. You will need to put everything that depends on the height of the image in the corresponding *onload* callback.

If you don't need to do your calculation as soon as the image is loaded, the [Salman A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995010/867310) is the better approach - put your logic when the *window#onload* event is fired, this ensures all external resources (including images) are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){ 
console.log($('#myimg').width() + 'x' + $('#myimg').height());

console.log($("#myimg").attr('src'));

})

working demo [http://jsfiddle.net/A5QJM/238/]